# Why snapshot.data returns null in FutureBuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

```dart
void main() {
  FutureBuilder<bool>(
    future: f(),
    builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
      bool data = snapshot.data; // Error
      return Container();
    },
  );
}

Future<bool> f() async => true;
```

I used `bool` in all the places and hence my `snapshot.data` should return a `bool` too but it returns `bool?`, why is that so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the implementation of data, it is:

```
T? get data;
```

The reason why data has a return type of `T?` and not `T` is the error. What if there was an error returned by your `Future`, in that case you'd receive a null value. You should use it like this:

```
FutureBuilder<bool>(
  future: f(),
  builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasError) {
      bool data = snapshot.data!;
    }
    return Container();
  },
)
```

Comment: Instead of `if (!snapshot.hasError)`, you could also do `if (snapshot.hasData)`.

Comment: You just put ! after the condition, like this snapshot.data!

Answer (score 1):

That is because the signature of `data` is `final T? data`, see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot/data.html  This makes sense, because when your async computation didn't produce a result yet, or an error occcured there is no data to return.

Comment: Actually the question indirectly was why is it `T? get data` and not `T get data`